# Como obtener nombre de una carpeta en php?

Tags: php

Tengo un link algo asi

```
http://midominio.com/carpeta1/carpeta2/quiero_este_nombre/carp.php
```

¿como podria tener el nombre de la carpeta? = **quiero_este_nombre**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías intentarlo de múltiples formas. Si siempre va a tener esa estructura, es decir, que el penúltimo parámetro es el nombre de la carpeta, lo podrías obtener así:

```
<?php 
$link = 'http://midominio.com/carpeta1/carpeta2/quiero_este_nombre/carp.php';
$link_sin_dominio = str_replace('http://midominio.com/', '', $link);
$grupos = explode('/', $link_sin_dominio);
echo $grupos[count($grupos) - 2];
?>
```

Lo que hace el código es deshacerse del `http://midominio.com/` con el `str_replace` para luego agrupar por grupos el resultante de las veces que se haya encontrado un `/` en el string anterior.

Como resultado nos da un array de ciertos valores donde para acceder al penúltimo lo imprimimos como `$grupos[count($grupos) - 2]` donde -2 singifnica que me regreso dos posiciones al final del array original utilizando la función `count` que retorna el número de valores de un array.